# multiparty for nodejs doesn't parse any uploaded file

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sails.js, multipart, skipper

I'm trying to perform simple upload file on node (multiparty) + angular (angular-file-upload) using [**sails.js**](http://sailsjs.org) on the backend. It seemed like frontend correctly sent a file to backend, but it appeared as the backend received nothing or responded with invalid request (inconsistently). form.parse part responded with empty fields and file. And I am pretty much stuck here, hours of googling to find out what was problem with multiparty but I couldn't find any useful information. Any advice would be appreciate

request header:

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:76632
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7iH8B208bfkavrKt
Cookie:sails.sid=s%3AY9YwxQC90Sq7pc3bp-scW7EH.%2B%2FYHfrTXCUzfPOBpeEt7VFH6Npw3s05Rqyfgu6DHVdg
Host:localhost:1337
Origin:http://localhost:1337
Referer:http://localhost:1337/kirill
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundary7iH8B208bfkavrKt
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="10923270_813578785376550_5210357694589684637_n.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundary7iH8B208bfkavrKt--
```

backend (node with multiparty):

```
upload: function(req, res) {
    var multiparty = require('multiparty');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var util = require('util');

    var form = new multiparty.Form();

    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, file){
        if (err) {
            res.writeHead(400, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
            res.end("invalid request: " + err.message);
            return;
        }
        console.log(file);
        res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
        res.write('received fields:\n\n '+util.inspect(fields));
        res.write('\n\n');
        res.end('received files:\n\n '+util.inspect(file));
    });
 }
```

frontend (angular with angular-file-upload):

```
$scope.upload = function () {
  //console.log($scope.file);

  if ($scope.file.data[0]){
    console.log("uploading file..");
    console.log($scope.file.data[0]);
    $upload.upload({
      url: 'api/v1.0/upload',
      method: 'POST',
      file: $scope.file.data[0]
    }).progress(function(evt){
      var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded/evt.total);
      console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.name);
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config){
      console.log('file ' + config.file.name + ' uploaded. Response: ' + data.status);
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: So is multiparty throwing an error, or is the console.log(file) printing null?

Comment: both, sometimes it gave me invalid request: stream ended unexpectedly or it gave me empty file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed to use skipper on backend which came with sails js by default. When sending post request to the backend, I needed to specify `fileFormDataName` to `filename` and I could use that name to get req.file('filename') on backend.

Answer (score 0):

Set the content-type to multipart:

```
$upload.upload({
      url: 'api/v1.0/upload',
      method: 'POST',
      data: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }, 
      file: $scope.file.data[0]
    }).progress(function(evt){
      var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded/evt.total);
      console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.name);
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config){
      console.log('file ' + config.file.name + ' uploaded. Response: ' + data.status);
    });
```